# Finding the index of an element that divide the array to two equal sums

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

take an array and find an index i where the sum of the integers to the left of i is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of i. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.

Why this code doesn't work all cases.
**why it is wrong ,**

```
def find_even_index(arr):
    i=1
    size=len(arr)
    sum_left=0
    sum_right=0

    for i in range(size):
        sum_right=sum(arr[i+1:]) #sum of all elements in right of i
        sum_left=sum(arr[:i-1] ) #sum of all elements in left of i
        if(sum_right==sum_left):
             return i

        return -1
```

Comment: I've edited the code in your question for clarity, but please learn how to use a code block *and* the preview option.

Comment: Can you give an example input array where this fails?

Comment: okey thank u,i will learn that

Comment: Note that your `return -1` statement is *inside* the for loop. That's your problem. (From what I can see, that was the same before my edit; since editing can mess up indentation, which is tricky in Python.)

Comment: this one for e.g :[20,10,-80,10,10,15,35]) & [10,-80,10,10,15,35,20]),

Comment: You can easily debug this (and similar programs) by inserting a few print functions at critical places, like `print(i, sum_right, sum_left)` just above the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few logical errors in your program. Firstly you declare `i` prior to the for loop, you should do it within the `range()` function itself, as the value of `i` resets on iterating it over the for loop. It should be like this:

```py
for i in range(1, size):
```

Also you are not doing correct slicing, remember that when you slice any list by giving `start` and `end` index, it ignores the `end` value, and only slices till `end - 1`.
For example,

```py
>>> a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]

>>> print(a[2:4]) # this will print the 2nd and 3rd element only, ignoring the 4th one
[30,40]
```

Also, if value of `i` starts from 0, `arr[:i-1]` will return whole array at once, so loop will break at first iteration.
For example,

```py
>>> a = [10,20,30,40,50]

>>> print(a[0:])
[10,20,30,40,50]

>>> print(a[:-1]) # index -1 refers to the last element of array
[10,20,30,40,50]
```

And you are using the `return -1` statement within the `for` loop, so the loop will break in the first iteration itself, you should do it outside the `for` loop.

Now your formatted code should look like this:

```py
def find_even_index(arr):
    size = len(arr)
    sum_left = 0
    sum_right = 0

    for i in range(1, size): # value of i initially set here as 1
        sum_right = sum(arr[i+1:])
        sum_left = sum(arr[:i]) # corrected the slicing
        if(sum_right == sum_left):
             return i
    return -1 # return method indented outside the for loop
```

Hope this answer helps! :)

If you can't understand the reasoning even now, you can read about the topics here:

1. [Negative Slicing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_negative_indexing.asp)
2. [Python range](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)